# Manual calculation of ARIMA(p,d,q) forecast

Tags: self-study, forecasting, arima, unit-root

I have obtained the answer on my own question [Manual calculation of ARIMA(1,1,0) forecast](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266967/manual-calculation-of-arima1-1-0-forecast), then I have seen the question and answer [Forecasting with ARMA models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184514/forecasting-with-arma-models-how-do-you-estimate-the-error-terms-for-use-with).

I'd like to write the formula to the manual calculation of `ARIMA(p,d,q)` forecast in common case. I'm starting with `ARIMA(2,1,2)` which is:

$$y_t  = \beta_1(y_{t-1}-y_{t-2}-\mu)+\beta_2(y_{t-2}-y_{t-3}-\mu)-(y_{t-1}+ \mu)+\varepsilon_{t}+\alpha_1\varepsilon_{t-1}+\alpha_2\varepsilon_{t-2}$$
or
$$y_t  = \underbrace{\beta_1(\Delta y_{t-1}-\mu)+\beta_2(\Delta y_{t-2}-\mu)-(y_{t-1}+ \mu)}_{part~AR(2)}+\underbrace{\varepsilon_{t}+\alpha_1\varepsilon_{t-1}+\alpha_2\varepsilon_{t-2}}_{part~MA(2)},$$

Lets say we have `n=252` observations and we want to calculate an one-step ahead `ARIMA(2,1,2)` forecast in-sample. This is easy in `R`:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(1)
n<-252
y<- runif(n, 9000, 10000)
fit1<-Arima(y[1:(n-1)], order=c(2,1,2))
coef(fit1)
#            ar1         ar2         ma1         ma2 
#    -0.49265434  0.07456189 -0.46064013 -0.53934992
```

We have fitted the `ARIMA(2,1,2)` model:

$$y_t  = -0.49265434(y_{t-1}-y_{t-2}-\mu)+0.07456189(y_{t-2}-y_{t-3}-\mu)-(y_{t-1}+ \mu)+\varepsilon_{t} -0.46064013\varepsilon_{t-1}-0.53934992\varepsilon_{t-2}$$
The one-step ahead `ARIMA(2,1,2)` forecast in-sample is

```
forecast(fit1, h=1)$mean[1] 
# [1] 9538.81
```

Now I'd like to do the the one-step ahead forecast in-sample manually. We can estimate the mean, $\mu$, and $\varepsilon_t$: 
$$\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}y_i,$$
$$\hat{\varepsilon_t}=y_{t-1} -\beta_1 y_{t-2} - \beta_2 y_{t-3},$$

But now I have a problem how to write the estimations $\hat{\varepsilon}_{t-1}$ and $\hat{\varepsilon}_{t-2}$.

**Question.** Are my representation of the ARIMA(2,1,2) model, i.e. $y_t$, and estimations $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\varepsilon_t}$ correct?